# How can I open the previous page in a new tab in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

If want to go back to the previous web page in Firefox, I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> or click on the "back" button:

[image: Firefox back button]

However, this opens the previous page in the current tab. How can I open the previous page in a new tab instead? Is there a keyboard shortcut for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while you click the "back" button opens your previous page in a new tab. (It also retains the history of that tab, so that you can press "back" again in the new tab to return to a previous page.)

Comment: Is there a keyboard shortcut for this?

Comment: Thank you. This is documented in [Use mouse shortcuts to perform common tasks in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/mouse-shortcuts-perform-common-tasks) under "Go Back or Forward but in a New Foreground Tab". Middle-click on the back button also works for opening the previous page in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit clunky but you could get a new tab by clicking the + at the end of the current tabs then view the history by clicking the icon that looks a bit like some books on a shelf then select the page which you want.